# Get the value of a hidden column in a gridview with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a function (below) that works wonderful but now I need to hide the column 'CustomerID' which gives me the value for var CustomerID = grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText; If I hide this column the function no longer works well it works but it's grabbing the wrong value. Can anyone help with this?

The hidden field looks like this...

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label id="lblCustomerId" runat ="server" text='<%# Eval("CustomerID")%>'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

function:

```
function mapSelectedClick() 
{
    var customerIDs = "";
    var grid = document.getElementById('<%=grdCustomers.ClientID %>');
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++)
    {
        var cell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];

        var CustomerID = grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
        for (var j = 0; j < cell.childNodes.length; j++)
        {
            if (cell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox")
            {
                if (cell.childNodes[j].checked)
                {
                    customerIDs += CustomerID.toString() + ',';
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        alert("Please select at least one customer to map.");
        return false;
    }

    customerIDs = customerIDs.substring(0, customerIDs.length-1);
    window.open("MapCustomers.aspx?CustomerIDs=" + customerIDs);
}
```

Comment: can you post some of the rendered / resulting html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be better to add `value="<%# Eval("CustomerID")%>"` to checkbox.

And the use it like:

```
if (cell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox")
{
    if (cell.childNodes[j].checked)
    {
        customerIDs += cell.childNodes[j].value.toString() + ',';
        count++;
    }
}
```

Or use the same name for all checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckedCustomers" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckedCustomers" value="3" />
```

In js:

```
var checkedCustomers = document.getElementsByName("CheckedCustomers");
var customerIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkedCustomers.lenght; i++)
{
    if(checkedCustomers[i].type === 'checkbox' && checkedCustomers[i].checked)
        customerIds.push(checkedCustomers[i].value);
}
var result = customerIds.join(',');
```